# Firebase performance monitor causing "D8: Unsupported source file type"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-performance, android-d8

I added

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

and when I ran `build` script I got

> /transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/dev/debug/174/module-info.class:
>   D8: Unsupported source file type

What kind of problem it could be?

I updated all plugins, play services, and Android Studio, but with no luck

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, no options for now. it works for dev build, but not for release

Comment: exactly, same issue I am facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed somewhere between [Android Studio 3.5 Beta 2](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/android-studio-35-beta-2-available.html) and [Android Studio 3.6 Canary 5](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/07/android-studio-36-canary-5-available.html), there were a bunch of similar issues with module-info.class.

In my case to fix issue I had not only update Android Studio, but also update gradle plugin.

Steps is:

1. Install new version alongside your stable version (You also can configure current version to use updates from canary chanel)

   [More info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview)

   [Download link](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)  (I downloaded 3.6 Canary 5)
2. After you installed new Android Studio update grade plugin:

   in
   `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
   chande distributionUrl to

   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip`
3. Don't forget `Build->Clean Project`

Comment: yep. it works. anyway I'd recommend to wait for AS 3.6 in stable channel. thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand the relation of this issue to AS. If I need to generate an apk, I could do it through gradle so how does AS solve this issue? :(

Comment: Sadly I don't know what is under the hood of AS, but I saw related issues in AS bug tracker, that's how I got to this solution.
Now I have 2 AS installed, one for everyday development and other for releasing builds.

Comment: For me, updating Android Studio from 3.5 to 3.5.1 was enough to fix the build in Android Studio. As for command line build, it's still broken; updating Gradle to 5.5 had no effect.

Comment: Jonik, note that updating Gradle wouldn't fix it, only upgrading the Gradle Android plugin (as mentioned in other answers, and in this one, but less specifically).

Answer (score 5):

I Solve This issue by updating gradle version

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

Comment: Worked for me! Would be nice to include what file this update happens in in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.0 fixes this. See [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131114388) and [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134093979) issue, both fixed.

(Unfortunately, in my project, [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57905161/56285) still remains even in 3.5.3.)

---

I started getting the same error after updating a (company internal) library dependency, but then I kept getting it even after reverting that update. Very strange!

```
> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForBetaRelease FAILED
R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.

.../transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/beta/release/66/module-info.class:
D8: Unsupported source file type
```

The only thing I found that helped was to do what the Gradle build output says and temporarily **switch back to ProGuard**, with:

```
android.enableR8=false
```

in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off Firebase-performance plugin. 
Android Studio 3.6 Canary 1 has this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131114388) too.
I didn't find another way to release build my project.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem with 3 steps:

1.update the "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip"

2.update the "classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3"

3.update the Studio 3.6.3

in other way(i don't like it)

//apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

...
//classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1"