# Gradle plugin 3.5.0: "Failed to transform artifact", "Execution failed for JetifyTransform"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetifier

We updated Android Gradle plugin from 3.4.2 to 3.5.0 (and Gradle from 5.1.1 to 5.4.1).

After that, the build started failing in a few submodules. Trying to `assemble` any build variant yields this (same error on the command line and in Android Studio):

```
> Failed to transform artifact 'bottom-navigation.aar (project :bottom-navigation)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
   > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: <project_root>/bottom-navigation/build/outputs/aar/bottom-navigation-release.aar.
      > Failed to transform '<project_root>/bottom-navigation/build/outputs/aar/bottom-navigation-release.aar' using Jetifier. 
        Reason: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=<project_root>/bottom-navigation/build/outputs/aar/bottom-navigation-release.aar, to=<project_root>/bottom-navigation/build/.transforms/9b2af95a5f0e0055110660c22ff05ab5/jetified-bottom-navigation-release.aar)'. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

#### What I've tried

- "Invalidate caches" in AS and also clearing all Gradle caches in `~/.gradle/caches` [as suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553123/56285)
- All the advice in [this somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57862066/56285)

  - I checked that the problematic modules use `apply plugin: 
    'com.android.library'` (instead of `com.android.application`)
  - I tried updating appcompat dependency to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` in affected modules and also removing that dependency

#### Update

It starts to look like something is wrong in Gradle plugin 3.5.0; builds behave erratically for me locally and on our CI machine.

For example, **clean builds are failing**: `./gradlew clean assembleBetaRelease` fails while `./gradlew assembleBetaRelease` works!

Also, sometimes I get `AAPT: error: attribute ... not found` instead of the above `Failed to transform artifact` error.

Reverting to Gradle plugin 3.4.2, all these problems disappear.

**Edit Oct 2019**: Still seeing this weird behaviour with Gradle plugin 3.5.1. **Edit Nov 2019** And 3.5.2. Upgrading to Gradle 5.6 didn't help either.

Comment: Did you missed `android.useAndroidX=true` & `android.enableJetifier=true` in **gradle.properties** file?

Comment: are using a React Native project?

Comment: @JeelVankhede: we have both of those in project-wide gradle.properties.

Comment: @sajadabbasi: no, this project has nothing to do with React Native.

Comment: @Jonik Please verify that you're not having any support library artifact in any module.

Answer (score -1):

A bit weird, but I got it working again. Apparently just a temporary glitch in Android Gradle plugin related to caching.

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483096/56285)** helped me:

> The simple way to solve this is to switch between your build variants. This refreshes the cached copies and resolves the issue.

I couldn't do that in Android Studio since the project sync was failing, but on the command line I tried another variant (in my case `./gradlew assembleBetaDebug` having used `./gradlew assembleBetaRelease` earlier). The build passed, and after that it worked for all all other variants too, and Gradle sync in Android Studio started working as well!

**Edit**: actually this is not completely solved; see updated question.

**Update 12/2019**: `bundle*` commands work fine, it's only `assemble*` that fails—still failing with Android Gradle plugin 3.5.3. Building in Android Studio works fine. Obviously this is not a common issue, and I don't know what exactly in the particular project I'm working on is causing this.

**Update 04/2020**: now with Android Gradle plugin 3.6.2 (and Gradle 5.6.4) builds work for me locally and I was able to update the project. On CircleCI, the build still *occasionally* fails with "Failed to transform artifact" but re-running fixes it. Go figure

Comment: Actually this problem is nastier than that — now I'm getting it again for example when I run `./gradlew clean assembleBetaRelease`, while `./gradlew assembleBetaRelease` works! And we ran into the same issue in our CI environment; haven't been able to fix that yet. I'm considering reverting back to 3.4.2 to make builds reliable again.

Comment: I also had this issue using Android Gradle plugin 3.5.3 with Gradle 5.4.1. I reverted the Android Gradle plugin to 3.4.2 and it works.